# how to get the difference between 2 tables in 2 different schema's in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, query, plsql

I am using Oracle 11G.

I have a table called **Tickets** in the schema called '**tickets1**"
I have the same table structure in another schema called '**tickets2**'

I want to find out

1. What data is the same in both tables?
2. What data is different?

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tickets(
>     ticket_number NUMBER NOT NULL,    
>     first_name VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
>     last_name VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
>     PRIMARY KEY(ticket_number)
> );
> ```

Comment: this looks like it would work on the same schema. How can I do this across two schema's?

Comment: You qualify table names with their respective schemas (provided you have enough privileges to read other user's data).

Comment: there are 3 responses but the original question has not accepted an answer. What would the correct answer be>

Comment: The one that works for you. In theory they all answer the question.

Comment: it didnt work at all

Comment: "it didnt work at all" is totally devoid of actionable information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mustaccio's point, there's nothing particular about a schema that prevents you from querying objects from different schemas within the same query (putting privileges aside - since that's a function of security, not a unique feature of schemas).

So you can use a `FULL JOIN` between the two tables across schemas with an appropriate `WHERE` clause like so to answer your questions:

```
-- Gets all rows that have the same primary key (ticket_number) between the two tables
SELECT * -- Replace * with only the columns you need, as using * is generally bad practice
FROM tickets1.Tickets T1
FULL JOIN tickets2.Tickets T2
    ON T1.ticket_number = t2.ticket_number
WHERE T1.ticket_number IS NOT NULL
    AND T2.ticket_number IS NOT NULL

-- Gets all rows that have different primary keys (ticket_number) between the two tables
SELECT * -- Replace * with only the columns you need, as using * is generally bad practice
FROM tickets1.Tickets T1
FULL JOIN tickets2.Tickets T2
    ON T1.ticket_number = t2.ticket_number
WHERE (T1.ticket_number IS NOT NULL AND T2.ticket_number IS NULL)
    OR  (T1.ticket_number IS NULL AND T2.ticket_number IS NOT NULL)
```

Note the above only compares the two tables by the primary key (`ticket_number`). Depending on your definition of "same data" / "different data", you may want to compare by other fields in the tables as well.

Comment: same means same values. 
ticket_number = 1 would be the same if ticket_number=1 on the other table.

Comment: @softwareisfun Then the above queries should be exactly what you need. Just wanted to make sure it wasn't possible for `tickets1.ticket_number = 1` to have a different `first_name` (for example) than in `tickets2.ticket_number = 1`.